# How to make Doxygen do syntax highlighting in @code containing XML fragments?

Tags: xml, doxygen, documentation-generation

I'm documenting a software library that manipulates an XML data format. I'd like to be able to write examples of XML in the documentation, and the natural way to do that would be

```
@code{.xml}
... xml here ...
@endcode
```

except that Doxygen does not do syntax highlighting on the contents like it does for other content such as C++.  (I've tried `.html` instead of `.xml` in there too, in case Doxygen supported HTML but not XML, but Doxygen doesn't seem to recognize either one.)

Does anyone have any suggestions for how to achieve syntax highlighting for XML code fragments?

<s>(And while on the topic, where can I find a list of the languages that Doxygen *does* recognize and highlight in `@code`/`@endcode` blocks?  I have not found it in the Doxygen manual so far.)</s> Assuming that Doxygen can only do syntax highlighting for the languages it can parse (which are listed for the variable EXTENSION_MAPPING, as pointed out by user "albert" in the comments below), then this implies the need for some external preprocessing.  Does anyone have suggestions for a clever way to do this?

Comment: Regarding the supported languages for @code. It is not explicitly written but from the used sentences one can derive that it are the languages as directly supported by doxygen (and possibly through EXTENSION_MAPPING).

Comment: That's an excellent point. The description of EXTENSION_MAPPING for Doxygen 1.8.8 suggests the list is IDL, Java, Javascript, C#, C, C++, D, PHP, Objective-C, Python, Fortran, and VHDL. Assuming that it can only highlight the languages it can also parse, then it would require some non-Doxygen processing to get syntax highlighting for something that is not in the list (e.g., XML). I will edit my question appropriately. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 3):

For others, like me, who may come across this many years after the original post, Doxygen supports syntax highlighting of the languages it supports via Markdown Extensions. Just use the [Fenced Code Blocks](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/markdown.html#md_fenced) or the [`\code`](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdcode) command with the explicit file extension specified.

I also found [a Javascript library that can be used with Doxygen](https://coderwall.com/p/ydwz3a/use-highlight-js-for-syntax-highlighting-in-doxygen-generated-documentation), but I haven't actually tried it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I was already using the `\code{}` command with an explicit file extension, as indicated in my original posting.

Comment: My bad. I guess I didn't read your post carefully. I see now that your problem was specifically syntax highlighting for XML, which you already knew was unsupported. That last link may do the trick help, though I haven't tried it. If I do, I'll come back and edit my response.